# SpringBoot Autowired Exception from external JAR

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a SpringBoot Application that works with another external JAR. When I try to @Autowired classes from the JAR , the SpringApp fails to load. I got "org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException". I know this has to do with SpringBoot not searching where the project classes are, but I can't figure out how to correctly tell where to look. I've added @ComponentScan, it worked with other internal classes, but not with this External JAR.

This is the class where I use the JAR methods:

```
package ar.com.tr.latam.care.ws.service.impl;

@Configuration

@ComponentScan({
"ar.com.tr.arz.expurgo", "ar.com.tr.arz.expurgo.logger", "ar.com.tr.arz.expurgo.logger.dao", "ar.com.tr.arz.expurgo.logger.impl","ar.com.tr.arz.expurgo.logger.model"})

@Import({ AppConfig.class, AplicacionCriteriosExpurgoServiceImpl.class, ClasificacionServiceImpl.class, ExcelReaderServiceImpl.class, ConversionServiceImpl.class})

@Service
public class ArzServiceImpl implements ArzService {

@Autowired
private ExcelReaderService excelReaderService;

@Autowired
private ConversionService conversionService;

@Autowired
private AppConfig appConfig;

...
}
```

And my Init.java class:

```
package ar.com.tr.latam.care;
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "ar.com.tr.latam.care.controller",  
"ar.com.tr.latam.care.filtro", "ar.com.tr.latam.care",
"ar.com.tr.latam.care.model.log", "ar.com.tr.latam.care.logger.impl", })

@EnableJpaRepositories
@SpringBootApplication

public class Init extends SpringBootServletInitializer { 


@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder     application) {
    return application.sources(Init.class);
}

/**
 * Main method.
 *
 * @param args String[].
 * @throws Exception Exception.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Init.class, args);
}
}
```

The JAR structure starts with "ar.com.tr.arz.expurgo" , but I can't find how to properly tell Springboot to check for those files there.

The error is "Could not autowire field: private ar.com.tr.arz.expurgo.services.ClasificacionService"

I've also tried adding the external JAR classes in the @ComponentScan Init class, but it also didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Add the packages to the ComponentScan in your Init class. ArzServiceImpl is a component, so it shouldn't contain any configuration.

Comment: Is the JAR available on class path ? Also, `@ComponentScan` should be on `Init ` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve it.
First I remove the @ComponentScan from the @Service, and only called it in my Init.java class (Start of the application)
THen I changed my Init packagein order to be on an upper level of the jar classes :

My Init.java was under package ar.com.tr.latam.care, the External JAR package classes were under: package ar.com.tr.expurgo. So, I changed my Init.java to be in package ar.com.tr, and every worked!